# jQuery Tools Overlay and Facebook Like Button

Tags: jquery, facebook-like

Using jQuery Tools overlay to open news articles in overlay.  Recently added Facebook JS code for the Like/Send buttons and it only works on the first click.  Doesn't run for second and subsequent clicks?  Any ideas?

You can see it at www.wiser.pitt.edu in the Recent News column on the home page.

Comment: If you are adding content to the document that has not been there when the JS SDK initially runs, then you have to use FB.XFBML.parse to get any Facebook tags in the newly added parts parsed as well. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/